# I couldn't embed ffmpeg package while trying to create an exe file for my python script

Tags: python, audio, video, ffmpeg, exe

I'm trying to create a `python script` that deals with `audios and videos`.
so, I need to use `ffmpeg` and it works -for details, I used a CLI program that deals with it, not me-, but when I tried to create an exe file using `pyinstaller`, it doesn't contain ffmpeg packages within it!
Now, if anyone want to use the app, he couldn't until he downloads ffmpeg independently, and it's a further step that makes it harder reach my app.
What is the solution/the way to embed ffmpeg with my app?

- What I'm expecting is to find a solution...
- What I've tried is that:
- I tried to search on google, but I found nothing.
- I tried to ask chatGPT and it gives me a script that doesn't work :)
- 

```
# my_app.spec
# Run with: pyinstaller my_app.spec

# Basic PyInstaller configuration
block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['main.py'],  # Replace 'main.py' with your Python script
             pathex=['.'],
             binaries=[('C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe', '.'), 
                       ('C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffplay.exe', '.'),
                       ('C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffprobe.exe', '.')],
             ...

             # Rest of the Analysis configuration goes here

             pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
                      cipher=block_cipher)

             exe = EXE(pyz,
                       a.scripts,
                       a.binaries,
                       a.zipfiles,
                       ...

                       # Rest of the EXE configuration goes here
)
```

Comment: You may find it easiest to use an ffmpeg wrapper for Python - e.g.: https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python

Comment: Thanks @Mick!
but I don't use ffmpeg directly, the tool I used which is -yt-dlp-, it used ffmpeg not me

Comment: If your code runs properly, I guess you need to put these binaries inside their own directories. Tell the code to read it from these directories while it is bundled.

Comment: @FT, yeah it does it really, before I used to put ffmpeg in PATH variable, but now putting ffmpeg in the same Dir as my exe app will work probably
Thanks

Comment: What I am trying to say looks like the following: `                                                        ``
a = Analysis(['main.py'],  # Replace 'main.py' with your Python script
             pathex=['.'],
             binaries=[('C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe', 'ffmpeg/'), 
                       ('C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffplay.exe', 'ffplay/'),
                       ('C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffprobe.exe', 'ffprobe/')],``` This way you can manage them inside their own directory. Most external utilities work this way.

Comment: @FT I tried but it didn't work, below is the last part of pyinstaller outptut

Comment: 24328 INFO: Looking for eggs
24331 INFO: Using Python library C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python310.dll
24331 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
24343 INFO: Warnings written to D:\PycharmProjects\Downloader app_yt-dlp\build\main\warn-main.txt
24529 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to D:\PycharmProjects\Downloader app_yt-dlp\build\main\xref-main.html

Comment: Try to conditionally set the absolute path of these resources in the two cases. Case 1 while you execute the code and Case 2 while the application runs from .exe, in the first case you just provide the path to these binaries on your computer. In the second case you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13790741/17161627) discussion. If the relative path to these resources exists that means you are running the application from your code otherwise you are executing exe.

Comment: There is a small issue, I didn't control ffmpeg path in anyway, the tool I use `yt-dlp` does it for me, and it works with two ways, either I putted the ffmpeg.exe in the same folder as my app, or I stored its path in the PATH variable in windows, not anything else

Answer (score 0):

## found a solution!

using `auto-py-to-exe.exe` will solve this issue, but when using `one file` option.
[how auto-py-to-exe.exe embed ffmpeg and ffprobe in your exe file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNZEP.png)